# How can I make Devanagari fonts render properly in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: fonts

Devanagari fonts appear broken like this:

[image]

It should appear this way

[image]

I have the same problem in browsers and office applications.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you include a screen shot?  I don't see a broken seeming font (not viewing from an Ubuntu browser at present).

Comment: I think he mistakenly wrote 6.0 LTS instead of 16.04 LTS.

Comment: indeed it's 16.0. it should look like something else in devanagari font. that i am not being able to type here

Comment: "it should look like something else in devanagari font" Hence my suggestion to include a screen capture image.

Comment: Is there more than one Devanagari font available you can test with?  For instance, like Times New Roman versus Baskerville/Baskervald for English?  That would eliminate the specific font file itself as the source of the problem.

Comment: The "correct" image helps, but it would help to also have a screen capture of the "broken" font as it appears on your screen.

Comment: IMO it should actually look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/g41JQ.png (see http://www.pmujjwalayojana.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/pradhan-mantri-ujjwala-yojana.jpg for comparison with a image from the Government of India). I use the [Noto Sans Devangiri](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) fonts precisely because they usually do the right thing with combining characters

Comment: Related [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008661/incorrect-rendering-display-of-devanagari-fonts-in-browsers-chrome-firefox-etc/1008803#1008803)

Answer (score 11):

Install the `fonts-deva` package, if you haven't already done so. Then create the file `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-prefer-devanagari.conf` with the following contents:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
        <alias>
                <family>serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Devanagari</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>sans-serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Devanagari</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>monospace</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Devanagari</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: i tried both but i didn't get fixed.  command yielded a lot of this             bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: @PratikGautam: Then you misunderstood the above somehow or made a typo.

Comment: says no such file or directory. can not find fontconfig

Comment: @Ekoji: You may need to create the directory: `mkdir -p ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d`

Comment: Worked for me. Many many thanks @GunnarHjalmarsson

Answer (score 2):

Download Google Noto Fonts (choose [Noto Sans Devanagari](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-deva)) and add it to **Home** > `.fonts`

If `.fonts` folder is not available in **Home** folder create it.

`.fonts` folder will be hidden by default. Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to see hidden files and folders before creating a .fonts folder.

You can use other Google Noto Fonts for any Indic language you would like to use.

If you want to have different font weights, choose fonts with those qualities.

This is just one simple way of doing it. There could be a thousand other ways to use Devanagari fonts in Ubuntu.

Comment: It should be mentioned that Noto Sans Devanagari is available in the Ubuntu archive via the `fonts-noto-hinted` package.

Answer (score 0):

Just Go to Settings of Browser And Select Gargi Font from Drop Down.

**For Firefox :**

1. Go to From Menu preferences.
2. Under Language & Appearance Default Font Set it To Gargi.
3. Click On Advance Tab Next To Default Font Settings.
4. Then Set Fonts For "Devnagari" from Drop Down.
5. Set Serif San-serif & Monospace to Gargi.

You Can Instantly Check using Google Typing Tool Online.

**For Chrome:**

1. Settings->Appearance Set All Fonts Value to Gargi From Drop Down Menu.
2. Then From Advanced Tab Install Extension For "Advanced Font Settings"
3. In Than Set All Fonts to Gargi.

Answer (score 0):

**This is happening because of fonts.**

To render any language text, font should support that text.
Default fonts of Ubuntu does not render Devanagari correctly.

In order to correctly show devanagari text, we need a font which is fully supporting devanagari.

To setup the correct font we need to do following steps.

1. Download [Noto Sans Devanagari](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-deva). This package contains many fonts.
2. Open `Home` folder and check for hidden files. You can use `Ctrl + H` for the same.
3. If you cannot find `.font` folder, create one.  Extract downloaded zip file into this folder. This step will integrate all these fonts into Ubuntu. So technically you can use any of these fonts in any of the software.
4. Open settings of chrome. Search for `font`. Click on `Customize Fonts`.
5. Change `Standard Font` to `Lohit Devanagari` or any other font which renders devanagari correctly.

To render devanagari correctly in any other software, we can do the same by selecting font as `Lohit Devanagari`.