# Strange garbage charachters in terminal, when typing Devanagari and some other Asian scripts

Tags: command-line, fonts, unicode

If I try to enter devangari or some other asian characters in the terminal, I get some strange circle characters after (or before?) some of them.

For example:

that is how the text looks like in my browser:

[image: in browser]

And that is how it looks like if I copy it in the terminal:

[image: in terminal]

As you can see, it is displayed completely wrong.

You can check if you have this problem also: just open hi.wikipedia.org and copy the text in a terminal (gnome-terminal for example).

At the same time, there is no problems with Japanese, Chinese, Russian, Arabic and some other (even doublewide) scripts.

**Update 1.** I see that it works in *konsole*. It is the only terminal that I've found (to the moment), which supports Indian fonts (at least Devanagari).

Are there any ways how I could setup/reconfigure/ other terminals so that they support such scripts?

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/855739/how-can-i-make-devanagari-fonts-render-properly-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: But I don't have this problem in browser and office applications, it is only in terminal. Now I am not sure at all, if devangari can be displayed correctly in a linux terminal

Comment: Which terminal program are you using?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: gnome-terminal, terminator, rxvt, mlterm, uxterm do not work

Comment: @IgorChubin with GNOME Terminal, terminator, etc. VTE would have to support these characters properly. Somebody wrote [patches for that 5 years ago](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vteindic/files/), but I doubt you can make those work today without significant work.

Comment: @muru Yes I know about these patches, but I doubt they can be applied to the modern terminals. I am really surprised that Indian scripts are not really supported in terminals nowadays, but it seems to be so

Comment: GNOME Terminal version 3.32 significantly improved the situation. Read: I believe it's pretty much fixed. A known issue is that the character under the solid block cursor still potentially draws such a circle. This is quite hard to fix (I'm also unsure what the exact desired behavior is). A workaround is to use I-beam or underline cursor shape.