# Devanagari consonant cluster wrong display

Tags: 16.04, fonts

I try to type त्र in the browser It should appear as follows:

[image]

But what is visible to me is this:
[image]

how do I fix this?

Comment: In which application(s) are you facing this issue? Font issue perhaps? Try changing the font. Also I don't know the exact usage, but if I'm not wrong, complex scripts like Arabic and Indic need the proper usage of [zero-width joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) & [zero-width non-joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) to render correctly.

Comment: happens only in the browser and that too so far I have used on 14.04 and 16.04 and this issue only happens in 16.04

Comment: Then probably a font issue, see if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/855739/how-can-i-make-devanagari-fonts-render-properly-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @user68186 I don't it's the same issue. I believe OP is not asking for help with typing, but with incorrect font rendering.

Comment: @user68186 I did not install any additional packages. This comes pre-installed and I never had problems before

Comment: @user68186: The Indic fonts are installed by default again as from Ubuntu 17.10 via the `fonts-indic` package.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the URL you are having trouble rendering the Hindi fonts with.

Answer (score 1):

### For 16.04 LTS and above:

Go to System Settings...> Language Support > Install Languages and install Hindi.

This was not needed before. It was sufficient to just enable the keyboard layout to use Hindi fonts.

Hope this helps

Comment: Did not work, I am afraid