# Devanagari fonts not rendering properly on 20.04 systemwide

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, fonts

Fonts are being rendered properly on browsers. The actual problem is Libreoffice Calc where devanagari fonts aren't being rendered properly:

[image: Libreoffice Calc]

Here you can see even if the cell properly converts the "Halant", the formula bar doesn't. The only workaround for now is to set default interface font in `tweaks` to other unicode font such as Arial Unicode MS. But I don't want Arial as my system font. Is there any way to assign Lohit Devanagari or other hindi font the primary font wherever hindi language is used? I've already done what [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855739/how-can-i-make-devanagari-fonts-render-properly-in-ubuntu-16-04) suggests to no avail.

Edit: on running `fc-list :lang=hi family` i can see FreeSans and FreeSerif being listed as hindi fonts, of which FreeSans typed hindi looks exactly like what the formula bar on Calc looks like. Is there a way to set other font in Libreoffice instead of FreeSans?

Comment: Is LibreOffice installed as a .deb file or a snap?

Comment: It's installed as a flatpak.

Comment: I see. If I was you I'd uninstall the flatpak, install the `libreoffice` .deb package, and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: The deb package is working as I wanted. What's going on? What's wrong with flatpak version?

Comment: Don't know, sorry. I know nothing about flatpak. If you really want to know, I'd suggest that you submit a new question about that specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `flatpak` apps don't seem to pick up fontconfig files, so replacing them with native `deb` packages will sort out the problem. However, oftentimes on new installations the font order mess up, so I made a `conf` file which makes specified font (`Lohit Devanagari` in this case) default for Hindi, and also puts some fallback fonts for your system when you don't want `Lohit Devanagari` to become default font for English SSA subtitles:

`mkdir -p /.config/fontconfig/conf.d/ && gedit /.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-hindi.conf`

and paste the following:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
    <fontconfig>
        <match>
            <test compare="contains" name="lang">
                <string>hi</string>
            </test>
            <edit mode="prepend" name="family">
                <string>Lohit Devanagari</string>
            </edit>
        </match>
    
        <alias>
            <family>sans-serif</family>
                <prefer>
                    <family>Ubuntu</family>
                    <family>Noto Sans Devanagari</family>
                    <family>Lohit Devanagari</family>
                    <family>Mukta</family>
                    <family>Arial Unicode MS</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
    
        <alias>
            <family>serif</family>
                <prefer>
                    <family>Noto Serif</family>
                    <family>DejaVu Serif</family>
                    <family>Liberation Serif</family>
                    <family>Noto Serif Devanagari</family>
                    <family>Lohit Devanagari</family>
                    <family>Arial Unicode MS</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
    
        <alias>
            <family>monospace</family>
                <prefer>
                    <family>Ubuntu mono</family>
                    <family>Noto Sans Mono</family>
                    <family>DejaVu Sans Mono</family>
                    <family>Liberation Mono</family>
                    <family>Noto Sans Devanagari</family>
                    <family>Lohit Devanagari</family>
                    <family>Arial Unicode MS</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
    </fontconfig>
```